# imported an obj with jpg texture but it looks burnt?

Tags: lighting

first use of newly installed latest blender, never used blender before, unlike meshlab and meshmixer my model with its jpg texture looks very dark and 'burnt'. why is the default lighting like this, for a beginner, to have to try and adjust lighting parameters to even get to see the model as normal is scary. What do I have to alter ? Where are the controls etc for this as I will never find them !, but I would far rather have it that the models that look fine in other progs are ditto in blender.
I see the model varies, darker in rhino4, meshmixer as per original, it was made in AliceVisionMeshroom.
I also see meshroom displays without the surface horribles, how become it looks good there and not in blender ?

[image]

Steve1

Comment: In the color management section, switch from filmic to sRGB.

Comment: Hi,I have imported the obj again but this time its silver,no jpg images on it, I go to scene at right, and open color management and it says :-

Comment: Hi,I have imported the obj again but this time its silver,no jpg images on it, I go to scene at right, and open color management and it says Display De sRGB and color space sRGB so now I am unsure why I cant see the jpg textures and also its already sRGB, but I need to see the jpg textures to see it again but how become its already sRGB and I have made no changes. I am importing a file from AliceVisionmeshroom cache folder called TexturedMesh.obj the same file as before and as opened into other progs and always its got the jpg images on it. this reply box doesnt allow for new para hit enter.

Comment: @Steve1 feel free to update your question rather than trying to fit more information into a comment.

Comment: Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your original post to update the question with additional information

Comment: I think it is a matter of lighting, where others have a general all round lighting good for modeling/texturing, blender is rendered with the one default sun lamp.